# Is it illegal for a passport cover to look like a real passport?

Tags: passports, legal

I've recently had to renew my British passport and I'm lazily shopping for a cover for it. In the course of my googling I find a few covers in different price ranges but all which very definitely look nothing like

There seems to be nothing available that actually matches the look of the old (or new) British passport or searching further anything that closely resembles another national passport.

Is there a specific international law that blocks the production of materials that look too much like passport covers? - exactly what is the line that must not be crossed in this? I see for instance plenty of covers that look very closely like a national passport, only in a weird colour.

Now I imagine trying to pass off a passport as something else is illegal. But that just a cover that resembles the real thing would not be allowed seems very curious.

Or could it be I'm just looking for a item so niche that even Chinese factories haven't knocked it out?

Comment: We used to have our passports in covers.  Found that many border officers did not like them and often (almost always) had to remove them from the cover.  Had a few grumpy officers tell us not to use them.  Now we just keep our passports in a large ziploc bag, and no covers

Comment: What is the purpose for which you need a passport cover?

Comment: Snubbing petty nonsense that wrecked a lot of people's lives with my own pettiness/no special reason. I then noticed the lack of realistic looking ones which perked my curiosity a bit more.

Comment: Why would anyone want a passport covers which ressembles an actual passport? But heed @Midavalo‘s advice: passport covers are not liked by immigration officers, and in most cases you are required to take them off, as this interferes with the ability to insert the passport into the scanner. Likewise when using e-gates.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I imagine trying to pass off a passport as something else is illegal. But that just a cover that resembles the real thing would not be allowed seems very curious.

[Looking at Amazon.co.uk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Passport+cover), passport covers resembling a British passport are plenty available (might be your tailoring that is not making them display, [example of one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SunTrad-Passport-Holders-Protector-Blocking/dp/B07SGJSKQY))

[Searching at Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Passport+cover) for passport cover, it yields quite a few for US passport

Same thing for :

- [Amazon.fr](https://www.amazon.fr/s?k=Passport+cover) (French passport)
- Some on [Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Veloflex-Case-for-Travel-Documents/dp/B006JO0H0E) (German passport)

Searching for [passport cover](https://fr.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-passport-cover.html?catId=0&SearchText=passport+cover) on AliExpress has those kinds of designs on the first result page (funny enough, searching for *fake passport* leads to even more of those products appearing)

Comment: Not true if you look closer at these links. They've all different colours and text than the real thing- one UK one for instance uses the real one on the cover pic but look in reviews and it's different, several clear ones use real passports in their pic, etc...

Comment: This proves nothing about its legality: AliExpress will cheerfully sell you *absolutely anything* legal or not. And all that crud will show up on eBay as well as Amazon due to Amazon Marketplace (3rd party sellers). Amazon uses *the smallest font on the entire page* to tell you it's a 3rd party seller and not themselves.  The presumption that "surely Amazon responsibly curates Amazon to only include legal products" can only be based on not knowing Jeff Bezos very well LOL.